# How to send array data of selected checkboxes to model in node.js

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb

I want to send the value of selected checkboxes from a form to the object model in node.js

I have got the value of checkbox in an array. Now i dont know how to send it to the model. I can send other values but i am confused on how to send over the array

**Model class in node.js:**

[image: Model class in node.js]

**Ajax data preparation**

[image: Ajax data preparation]

I want to get the value of `departments[]` from ajax to `hosDepartments` in model

[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYU5q.png)

[Response i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A90u1.png)

[Sending data to api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePgjp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already have a Webapi to communicate with the client,
if yes just use [fetchapi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send the data as a json body to your api, and from there you parse it into your model.

```js
fetch('yourUrlOfTheServer.tld:yourPort/yourEndpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(hospitalData)
});
```

If not, use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com) to make on like this

```js
var express = require('express') //Express Js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser') //You need a body parser to get the body sent by the client

const app = express(); //init express

app.post('/insert', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
    //You can get the Bodydata you have send via req.body.hosName
    var x = new hostpitalschema;
    x.hosName = req.body.hosName;
    x.hosDetails = req.body.hosDetails;
    [...]
    //You could probably also use forEach, but I believe this is better performancewise.

    //insert d into db, or whatever your gonna do woth it
})

app.listen(6969, function() {
   console.log(`App is listening on Port 6969`)
})
```

You'd send a request from the client like this

```js
fetch('yourUrlOfTheServer.tld:6969/insert', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(hospitalData)
});
```

Comment: I do have an API created. What i want to is to send the array to hosDepartments. But I am getting it in different format. What i want is hosDepartments:[{department:'General'},{department:'ENT'}] but what i am getting is 'hosDepartments[]':['department:General','department:ENT'] . I have included my api and the response i am getting to the question. And thanks for the timely response

Comment: @manjish whats the output of the console.log of the api ln. 113?

Comment: check the Response i am getting link

Comment: @manjish Check out this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zsaqx83t/1/ it works for me. What could be the issue is that you forgot to JSON.stringify(str) it as you have not shown your xhr/ajax/fetch/axios request.